# A little confused with Big O

Tags: big-o

So I have a quick question on how to verify the big O of a function.

for example: a quicksort algorithm sorting an array of 5000000 element yields a time interval of 0.008524 seconds, running the same algorithm with 1000000 element yields 0.017909.  How would I check the big O if my quicksort is/is not big O of n*log(n)??

What I think I understand: n increased by 2  thus the runtime should increase by 2*log(2)?

f(n) = 0.008524 -> n log (n)

f(2n) = 0.017909 ->2n*log(2n)

Comment: If you'd like to verify it is resembling O(nlog(n)) performance based on time measurements, you can plot the running time for different n. Take enough data points (>5) and plot the running time for each sample. Then compare the shape of the curve to linear/O(n), quadratic/O(n^2), logarithmic/O(log(n)), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation is asymptotic.  That means it only applies in the limit as n gets large.

There are many reasons why sorting with 50 and 100 elements might not track O(n log n), caching effects being a likely candidate.  If you try 100,000 versus 200,000 versus 1 million, you will probably find it tracks a little better.

Another possibility is that most quicksort implementations are only O(n log n) on average; some inputs will take longer.  The odds of encountering such a pathological input are higher for 50 elements than for 100,000.

Ultimately, though, you do not "verify" big-O run time; you *prove* it based on what the algorithm does.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation is not normally concerned with run-time in seconds.  It's concerned with *the number of operations* that were carried out by the algorithm.  The only way to establish that is to look at the code for the function.

Not only will run-time be affected by lower-order terms (remember that big-O notation only concerns itself with the *highest-order* term), but also things such as program startup overhead, cache efficiency and branch prediction.

Having said all that, it's possible that none of these other effects will be significant in your case.  In which case, if *n* is doubled, then you would expect the run-time to increase from *k.n.log(n)* to *k.2n.log(2n) = k(2n.log(2) + 2n.log(n))*.

Comment: I am in a lower level class and in the assignment, we are trying to use the runtime to verify the predicted nlog(n). We are not looking for the exact value and description, just a good understanding of whether or not it assumes a Big O of n log n...if that makes sense?

Comment: @kingcong3: Ok.  But you'll definitely need more than 2 data points to distinguish between *O(n)*, *O(n^2)*, *O(n.log(n))*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of points to keep in mind: first and foremost that as you change sizes, the hardware (at least on a typical computer) will have an effect as well. Particularly, when your data becomes to large to fit in a particular size of cache, you can expect to see a substantial jump in run-time that's completely independent of the algorithm in question.

To get a good idea of the algorithm proper, you should (probably) start by comparing to some algorithm with a really *obvious* complexity, but working with the same size of data. For one obvious possibility, time how long it takes to fill your array with random numbers. At least assuming a reasonably typical PRNG, that should certainly be linear.

Then time your algorithm, and see how it changes *relative* to the linear algorithm for the same sizes. For example, you might use some code like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

class timer { 
    clock_t begin;
    std::ostream &os;
    std::string d;
public:
    timer(std::string const &delim = "\n", std::ostream &rep=std::cout) 
        : os(rep), begin(clock()), d(delim)
    {}
    ~timer() { os << double(clock()-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << d; }
};

int main() { 
    static const unsigned int meg = 1024 * 1024;

    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Size" << "\tfill\tsort\n";
    for (unsigned size=10000; size <512*meg; size *= 2) {
        std::vector<int> numbers(size);
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << size << "\t";
        { 
            timer fill_time("\t");
            std::fill_n(numbers.begin(), size, 0);
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                numbers[i] = rand();
        }
        {
            timer sort_time;
            std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I graph both the time to fill and the time to sort, I get something like this:

[image]

Since our sizes are exponential, our linear algorithm shows a (roughly) exponential curve. The time to sort is obviously growing (somewhat) faster still.

Edit: In fairness, I should probably add that log(N) grows so slowly that for almost any practical amount of data, it contributes very little. For most practical purposes, you can just about treat quicksort (for example) as being linear on the size, just with a somewhat greater constant factor than filling memory. Growing the size linearly and graphing the results makes this more apparent:

[image]

If you look carefully, you can probably see the upper line showing just a *slight* upward curve from the "log(N)" factor. On the other hand, I'm not sure I'd have noticed any curvature at all if I hadn't already known that it *should* be there.

Answer (score 0):

Two data points aren't really enough.

However, 2*n*log(2*n) = 2*n*(log(n) + log(2)), so you can see that the multiplier should be approximately 2*log(2) when you double the size.  That looks plausible for the numbers you gave.  You should add a few more points and double check.

Note that there is likely to be some constant term in your timing, at least if you include program startup in there - it might be significant.  If, on the other hand, you only time the sorting phase without the startup, it is more accurate.  You should repeat the process over many permutations of the input data to ensure you get a representative set of values.

Comment: but 2 log (2) ~= 0.60. my time values, 0.017909/0.008524 ~= 2.1 isnt that a big jump to call "plausible"?? also the timer is started just before the function and stop right after.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you are looking at, it is dependent on how long it takes for the method to run through the 50 elements compared to 100, not the timing itself. Like if I was iterating through an array, that would be linear time O(n), because the array would has to go through each index to the end. N represents how large the array would be. Besides, Big O notation is meant for the overall scheme of things, in the long run. If you averaged the timing for 50, 100, 1000, 100000, 1000000, you would see on *average* it would have a O(nlog(n)).