# How do you calculate the value of N for similar efficiency in running time algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, performance

I'm attempting to understand the calculations of running times, however, I've reached an impasse. If you have two functions, say

```
    (N^3 + 2N^2 + 6N + 3)
```

and

```
    (6N^2 + 4N + 10)
```

How do you approach finding the value of N at which the two algorithms reach the same efficiency? I would prefer to not be given the actual value, but how to approach the problem. I plugged in 0, 1, 4, 10, and 67 (the choices given) for N^3 and 6N^2, but in every case N^3 was always smaller (except for 0 of course). Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: If you find the term with N^3 to be always smaller, then you should recalculate.

Comment: Where are you plugging these numbers in? Calc.exe? Some programming language? A piece of paper?

Comment: Just equate the two expressions

Comment: It depends on hidden constants. Maybe you don't need big-O notation here (and you want just to solve equation).

Comment: You're correct, @DirkHerrmann. I did indeed miscalculate.

Comment: What does this have to do with Big-Oh and time complexity? You should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - What do you mean "what does this have to do with Big-Oh and time complexity"? The two functions are algorithms that represent the running times of a piece of code. It is based on my textbook chapter on Big-Oh Notation. How can it not be related? I'm almost afraid to come to this website sometimes because people like me eventually become apprehensive about simply asking for help. If I approached the problem incorrectly, then it's obviously because I didn't understand how to approach it. I have a textbook, and a PDF lecture, not an instructor in front of me.

Comment: Relax mate. Running time doesn't equal complexity,read all the answers and then edit your question to be more useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're doing this incorrectly. More accurately, *what* you're trying to do is incorrect, at least as a use of big-O notation.

First of all, big-O notation discards all but the highest-order part of a polynomial, so your two examples are properly O(N<sup>3</sup>) and O(N<sup>2</sup>) respectively. Big-O notation is related to behavior as N approaches infinity.

Based on that, we quickly see that big-O notation (in general) simply isn't the right tool to use for the job you're trying to do. Now, perhaps your use of `O` was really the mistake here, and you meant that in the first case, the time is proportional to N<sup>3</sup> + 2N<sup>2</sup>+6N+3, and in the second case to 6N<sup>2</sup>+4N+10.

If that's the case, then you just need to solve for the point at which the two polynomials are equal:

N<sup>3</sup> + 2N<sup>2</sup>+6N+3 = 6N<sup>2</sup>+4N+10

...which we'd then transform to something like:

N<sup>3</sup> - 4N<sup>2</sup> + 2N - 7 = 0

From there it's a matter of simple algebra to solve for N.

N ( N<sup>2</sup> - 4N + 2) = 7

In this case, I'd tend to assume that the lower-order terms become more and more approximate, so (for example) by the time you get to the constant term (i.e., the on that doesn't involve `N` at all) that it's quite approximate indeed. As such, I probably wouldn't worry a lot about getting those terms precisely correct when solving for N. Based on this, we can transform the equation above to:

N (N-2)(N-2) = 7

Then I'd cheat some more and observe that we have N-2 as two of the factors, and N as the third, so N is somewhere *around* the cube root of 7 + 2, which works out to about 4. Since one of the factors was really N, not N-2, we know that's not *quite* right, but in reality N can only be an integer, so it's probably close enough. If you wanted to check that, you could plug 3, 4, and 5 into the original polynomials, and compute the values. My guess would be that for 3 you get a difference in one direction, and for 5 in the other direction, and a difference for 4 that's smaller than for either 3 or 5.

Four is just a rough approximation of the math for those polynomials though. It might not work out that way in real life. Given the difference in degree of the polynomials, it wouldn't be particularly surprising for the real break-even point to differ from that somewhat--it might easily be 3 or 5, and quite possibly even 2 or 6. I, for one, would really be pretty surprised if it were as large as, say, 100 or probably even 50 though.  That's a lot of why I didn't worry much about being particularly precise in the original computation.

I should probably add that in most real cases you don't start with anything nearly as precise as "N<sup>3</sup> + 2N<sup>2</sup>+ 6N + 3" either. In reality, you frequently start with enough noise in your measurements that it's difficult to even be certain what the most significant term of the polynomial is. Consider, for example, some real data I showed in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210325/179910) about the time taken for a quick sort. This is an algorithm that's been studied (and tested) heavily over the years, so there's little real question that it's expected run-time is approximately N log N. Nonetheless, based on the raw times I used to draw the graph in that post, it would be hard to have any certainty that it was indeed N log N instead of just linear.

As such, I'd warn that in my estimation, the basis of this question is fairly questionable (even at best) except as a purely intellectual exercise.

Comment: It's two polynomials not two equations

Comment: @novice: they're similar for the basic math part, but you didn't go into anything about the nature of big-O notation, and how it's inapplicable to the problem at hand.

Comment: I just want to point out (though you mentioned it in passing), that even if you find the value of N for which the two polynomials are equal, that doesn't mean that the two runtimes would be the same for the two algorithms because of all of the other factors related to running the two. So even saying that it would be equal when N is 4 is being over precise. The only real information you can gain in this manner is to know that one algorithm is more efficient than the other for even very small values

Answer (score 2):

The way you ask the question ("for which N do the algorithms have the same efficiency") indicates a misconception: If you have two algorithms then you can describe their respective complexity with O(f1(N)) and O(f2(N)), where f1 and f2 are both terms depending on N.  That does not mean, however, that for the value(s) of N for which f1(N) = f2(N) is fulfilled the two algorithms will take identical (or even close) time to compute: The actual computation times can still vary by arbitrary amounts for any given N.  The O(N) notation only describes the asymptotic time complexity, which means, the way in which computation time will develop when N goes in the direction of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Just equate the two polynomials and solve for N to evaluate when both programs have the same efficiency(for which N)

Comment: Typing answers without thinking.

Comment: See Jerry Coffin's answer.

Comment: not the same. I can show why you are wrong.
 O(N^3 + 2N^2 + 6N + 3) = O(N^3);
O(6N^2 + 4N + 10) = O(N^2);
N^3 = N^2;
N = 1.
I can prove that N = 2 with some manipulations also.

Comment: He had no use of O(n) notation and just wants to find out when they have "same efficiency"

Comment: Yes, @novice, your'e right. I typed my question title incorrectly. I'm not looking for Big-Oh, I'm looking at how to find the value of N where the efficiency matches.

Comment: Also edit the question to remove the O() its a bit confusing

Comment: Can you really not see the difference in quality between your answer and Jerry's? Your answer is a single line that gives the OP a direction to investigate and Jerry's answer explains why he is misunderstanding the problem and walks him through the right approach.

Comment: Sorry, @novice, I typed the questions exactly as they were shown. But for the sake of simplicity, I'll edit them out. :)

Comment: @KevinWells I see it clearly -but the facts are a) my answer was the fastest and to the point. b) it did not warrant a downvote just because sashaMN has no idea about what the OP was asking for, it was short because i was on my mobile- but no worries, I really do not want to argue the point - cheers :)

Comment: I agree that it didn't deserve a downvote, you just seemed to actually not know why people were preferring his answer to yours (you asked both here and on Jerry's answer), so I though I would explain

Comment: Not at all, Jerry's is the perfect answer, i was simply pissed off about the downvote - which by the way he still has not removed (I still am @@), I asked on Jerry's answer merely to confirm if i had not missed anything